# Predict the output based on multiple input variable using XGBoost in Python

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, xgboost, kaggle

I am new to xgboost and trying to do the following things.

1. predict the output variable using input variables
2. Trying to find out which input variables are having more correlation (good relationship) with the output variable.

I am not able to get the correct results w.r.t both 1 and 2. I am a beginner to this xgboost, plz help me out in this. Thanks in advance.

Referred: (Jason Brownlee blog, kaggle)

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def main():
    #Removing the blank fields and filling with mean values
    def xls_to_csv():
        df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\ML material - docs\L90\Abhijit's task\extraction-M1947-B3,B6andB5\S2\ML_9820G_PCMvsS2_PCM_FE_BE_ML_S2-2017-02-14-103304-836.xlsx")
        df.drop(['aggregation','lot','____________________wafer','wafer','lot wafer'],axis=1, inplace=True)
        df_1 = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()),axis=0)
        df_1.to_csv(r"C:\ML material - docs\L90\Abhijit's task\extraction-M1947-B3,B6andB5\S2\ML_9820G_PCMvsS2_PCM_FE_BE_ML_after_impute.csv", index=False)

    #xls_to_csv()   
    #Applying normalization
    df1 = pd.read_csv(r"C:\ML material - docs\L90\Abhijit's task\extraction-M1947-B3,B6andB5\S2\ML_9820G_PCMvsS2_PCM_FE_BE_ML_after_impute.csv")
    for feature in df1.columns: # Loop through all columns in the dataframe
            if df1[feature].dtype == 'object': # Only apply for columns with categorical strings
                df1[feature] = pd.Categorical(df1[feature]).codes
    df2 = (df1 - df1.mean())/df1.std()
    df2 = df2.dropna(axis=1,how='all',thresh=None)

    df2.to_csv(r"C:\ML material - docs\L90\Abhijit's task\extraction-M1947-B3,B6andB5\S2\ML_9820G_PCMvsS2_PCM_FE_BE_ML_after_impute_after_nml.csv", index=False)

    def get_data():
        train = pd.read_csv(r"C:\ML material - docs\L90\Abhijit's task\extraction-M1947-B3,B6andB5\S2\ML_9820G_PCMvsS2_PCM_FE_BE_ML_after_impute_after_nml.csv")
        y_train = train.pop('7;IDDQ_IPD;tested_pct;sbin')
        features = train.columns
        x_train = train[features]
        return features, x_train, y_train

    features, x_train, y_train = get_data()

    final_train,final_test = train_test_split(x_train, test_size = 0.2)
    final_y_train,final_y_test = train_test_split(y_train, test_size = 0.2)

    #XGboost modelling starts here
    xgdmat = xgb.DMatrix(final_train, final_y_train) # Create our DMatrix to make XGBoost more efficient
    our_params = {'eta': 0.1, 'seed':0, 'subsample': 0.8, 'colsample_bytree': 0.8,'objective': 'reg:linear', 'max_depth':3, 'min_child_weight':1} # Grid Search CV optimized settings

    final_gb = xgb.train(our_params, xgdmat, num_boost_round= 1000)
    importances = final_gb.get_fscore()
    importance_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Importance': list(importances.values()), 'Feature': list(importances.keys())})
    importance_frame.sort('Importance', inplace = True)
    importance_frame.to_csv(r"C:\ML material - docs\L90\Abhijit's task\extraction-M1947-B3,B6andB5\S2\ML_9820G_PCMvsS2_PCM_FE_BE_ML_scores.csv", index=False)

    # Analysing the test results
    testdmat = xgb.DMatrix(final_test)
    y_pred = final_gb.predict(testdmat)
    print y_pred,"\n",final_y_test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Its kind of difficult to evaluate what you might be doing wrong without access to any error msg or data input/results.

But without getting into detail about your specific case example, my suggestion to you as a beginner with xgboost would be to try to replicate a few demo/examples to get a better understanding of how it works.

A great blog/site for begginers is Jason Brownlee's. (edit: just realized you mentioned him)

An example case worked by him can be found here: http://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-first-xgboost-model-python-scikit-learn/

He also has some ebooks on ML and xgboost, they are really good starting material (better than most video courses)

A personal sugestion of mine would be for you to first do your code line by line when building a model instead of doing a one-instance application/function like you have done. That way its easier to evaluate when/if a mistake is made.

edit 2: another good advice is to use the xgboost wrapper for python (xgb.XGBClassifier) which is easier to understand/work with at first instance.

Hope that helps,